# All my lightswitch applications are showing a white blank screen in Desktop mode

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I created a new LightSwitch solution in Silverlight web mode and it was working fine, then I changed it to silverlight desktop mode in order to get access to AutomationFactory, however in desktop it refuses to show anything other then a white blank screen.

I opened my older lightswitch silverlight desktop solutions, and if I run any of those in debug or in release mode they are all showing a white blank screen! They were working fine before, I don't know what happened.

There is a setting in **X.DesktopClient -> Properties -> OutOfBrowserSettings.xml** where if you set

```
<SecuritySettings ElevatedPermissions="NotRequired" />
```

Instead of "Required", then the application works in desktop mode and is no longer showing a blank screen, however it behaves as if it was a web application, (It doesn't have access to AutomationFactory and the export to excel doesn't work etc...) so this won't do.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

**Details**
Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013, LightSwitch 2013, Silverlight 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was missing references to an extention I'd added (DevExpress Reporting). I had to highlight the references and set their `Copy Local` properties to `True`